# How to commit transaction in Spring with jdbc template ..?

Tags: java, spring

i am new to Spring ..i was trying to do some database transactions using jdbc template....the programs are running fine but when i am fetching some data from database after some `DML` operations ,it is not showing updated data....after manually committing in the database the refreshed data are showing....Is there any way to commit the database from program it self using jdbc template....!! I am using Spring 4.1.6 version...Please help...

```
public void create(Student s){
        String sql = "insert into student(id,name,age)values(?,?,?)";
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql,s.getId(),s.getName(),s.getAge());
        System.out.println("Row Inserted");
        //Logic for commit...???
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Add `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation to your config and mark the method as `@Transactional`.

Thus after exit the method transaction is committed (if no Exception was thrown)

See [the example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/managing-transactions/)

Answer (score 5):

```
@Transactional
```

add this notation above every method of dao .This will automatically do transaction management.